# How can I use Magento cache in widget?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I'm developing RSS feed widget for Magento. Now I need to use Magento cache to store feeds, so that feeds are not loaded on every request. How can I store my own items to Magento cache or is that possible at all?

What I need is :

```
// My item
$myItem = "My feed";

// Put stuff to cache
$cache->put("MyCacheId", $myItem);

// Get stuff from cache
$cache->get("MyCacheId");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mage_Core_Model_App::saveCache($data, $id, $tags=array(), $lifeTime=false)
```

is your desired method here.

In core you'll often find method access like follow:

```
Mage::app()->saveCache(serialize($myData), $myCacheKey, ...)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the widget into a block and cached this block